# AWS: port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I am running 16.04 Ubuntu locally, I am running a AWS instance with an Ubuntu 16.04 image. I am unable to request this site with curl (using to test for internet connectivity)

`curl https://oddsportal.com`

It returns

`* Failed to connect to oddsportal.com port 443: Connection timed out`

Here are my outbound and inbound rules respectively.
[inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHTbO.png)
[outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ozx0.png)

These are the results from netstat

[netstat -nlp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLbn.png)

Comment: before digging more into configs, your ```netstat``` command was something like ```netstat -aln``` ? Do you understand ```netstat``` output? Basically there is no service listening on port 80 or 443. You have to start your webserver first!

Comment: After you start your web server, the next barrier is usually the security group, internet gateway, and routing.

Comment: yes I ran that command, as I saw others had used it in similar questions. I don't know why those ports aren't open when I have allowed them in my inbound and outbound rules. By starting the webserver do you mean running the AWS instance on my machine?

Comment: your site need to be served by a running webserver like nginx, apache etc. What is your webserver ? you need to start it before trying to access the site

Comment: @vx3r To be clear, this isn't my site. I am simply using the curl comand to determine if my AWS Instance has internet connection, so I can eventually run a Scrapy script

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like https://oddsportal.com isn't configured correctly

Try
https://www.oddsportal.com/

Comment: same response unfortunately.